# AngularJs facebook like mention: how to start mention suggestions without the trigger character e.g. '@'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ment.io

I am using a third party library **mento.io** [Github](https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io) for achieving my requirements.

This library is good enough to show suggestion after a specific character but my requirement is that user should get suggestions as soon as it starts typing like IntelliSense on some editor.

**Problem**

How to start the suggestion when an user hits any character. Right now its only working with `@` symbol

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module('app', ['mentio']);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.people = [
        { label: 'Joe' },
        { label: 'Mike' },
        { label: 'Diane' }
    ]

    $scope.myval = '';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    
    
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />-->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/dist/mentio.js"></script>
 
 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body><div ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>

  <input type="text" mentio id="test" mentio-id="'test'" mentio-typed-text="typedTerm" mentio-trigger-char="'@'" mentio-items="people"
   ng-model="myval" />
 </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use bootstrap typehead with angualar

Comment: I have gone to this git hub project but this is not satisfying my requirements as it is only showing suggestions for whole text input string but I want suggestion for everyword like intellisence 

https://github.com/davidkonrad/angular-bootstrap3-typeahead

Answer (score 0):

If you need to figure this out with mentio.io lib, take a look at this pull request:

https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io/pull/94

I was faced the same problem using mento.io and just changed framework: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete

Comment: but it suggests once per input textbox. I want something like `intellisense`. just like the suggestions come when you type in text editor

Comment: if you need "intellisense", take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/jKnzG

Comment: or if you want not dropdown: https://designshack.net/articles/javascript/create-a-simple-autocomplete-with-html5-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

`mentio-trigger-char="''"` seems to work, seems a little bit akward for me but it works

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module('app', ['mentio']);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.people = [
        { label: 'Joe' },
        { label: 'Mike' },
        { label: 'Diane' }
    ]

    $scope.myval = '';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    
    
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
  crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />-->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/dist/mentio.js"></script>
 
 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body><div ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>

  <input type="text" mentio id="test" mentio-id="'test'" mentio-typed-text="typedTerm" mentio-trigger-char="''" mentio-items="people"
   ng-model="myval" />
 </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is problem in it. Suppose you type `j` and press `enter` then the text/word will be `jjoe` instead of `joe`

Comment: did you read https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io/issues/58 already ?